# After type init command package.json not created my directory

Tags: node.js, express, npm-install

$ npm init
This utility will walk you through creating a package.json file.
It only covers the most common items, and tries to guess sensible defaults.

See `npm help json` for definitive documentation on these fields
and exactly what they do.

Use `npm install <pkg>` afterwards to install a package and
save it as a dependency in the package.json file.

Press ^C at any time to quit.
package name: (test1)

Comment: What is the output you get for `npm init`?

Comment: This was the output.now i solved the issue.just type npm init -y command.thanks for trying to help.